# Unable to call function in meteor package using method?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to use a geocoder package I found on atmosphere (aldeed:geocoder) which use the node-geocoder package. The meteor package specifies that in order to perform a new geocode, i'm to create a new instance of GeoCoder, and then call the geocode method on it, passing in an address string, like so:

```
var geo = new GeoCoder();
var result = geo.geocode("location");
```

If I put the above in a server.js file in the server file of my app and console.log result, I get an object printed to the terminal as expected. The problem I'm running into is when I try to call this using a meteor method, in response to user input from a search box. My template helper has this in it:

```
Template.layout.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    var search = {
        location: $(e.target).find('[name=search]').val()
    }

    console.log(search.location);

    Meteor.call('getGeoCode', search.location, function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    });
}

});
```

and the collection's file, forecasts.js has this in it:

```
Forecasts = new Mongo.Collection('forecasts');


    Meteor.methods({
        getGeoCode: function(search) {
            var geo = new GeoCoder();
            result = geo.geocode(search);
            return result;
        }
    });
```

But when I try it out, I get an error in the console that tells me that GeoCoder is undefined. Specifically:

> "Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'getGeoCode'" ReferenceError: GeoCoder is not defined

So, what's going on here? Why isn't it possible to create a new GeoCoder instance in that method and call it like I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from geocoder's [package.js](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-geocoder/blob/master/package.js), the `GeoCoder` namespace and files are only exported to the server. Your error indicates that the method is defined on the client. When you invoke the method, the client attempts to run its version and throws an error because it doesn't have access to the `GeoCoder` API.

The easiest solution is just to define this method in a file under your `/server` directory. Alternatively you could wrap the shared method definition with a check for `Meteor.isServer`.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Okay, so if the method is defined in a file in the /server directory, can it still be called in a template helper?

Comment: Yes, however your helpers should not have have side effects. A helper's job is to reactively read and/or translate data, not to change state. A better place for a method call is in `rendered`, `created`, or in a event handler.